# Getting notification in system bar for an update in a webpage

Tags: android, notifications, android-webview

I am new to android programming. I am designing an android app for my college. I have made a webview that loads up a webpage named **events.html**. how can i make it such that whenever new events are added to the webpage, **a notification in the system bar of the app will appear** about that events if the user is connected to the internet. Please help me. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Store the HTML file in your app's database/shared preference/file (in Java object form will be more useful for later comparison).
2. Periodically check for a new file (at some interval), temporarily storing the result. This will likely be in an Android `Service`
3. Compare the temporary file to the one you had stored previously.
4. If the two files are different, then use `NotificationManager` to create a new `notification`

Without all of this, it looks like you would need to have a server with push notifications (or Google Cloud Messaging) available that pushes notifications to your college's app users whenever that is a new event. This is an expensive (more demanding option compared to above).

Comment: But the events page is stored in some other server...it is not stored in app's database

Comment: **You** will need to store it locally.

Comment: and how to use Google cloud messaging service ?

Comment: Google `Google cloud messaging service`. It might not be feasible if you are newer to Android development.